# One to Many Relationship Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

learning Mongo DB coming from Rails and I'm having a little trouble understanding how to establish a connection between two of my models.

I three models: Site, Article, and User (not touching user for the moment - just focusing on Site and Article).

Site Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const SiteSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    articles: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'article' }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('site', SiteSchema)
```

Article Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    source: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'site' }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('article', ArticleSchema)
```

What I'm essentially trying to establish here is that a site has many articles, and an article only comes from one source (a site). Where the trouble is is that I can create articles separately, and I can create sites in my DB -> the site looks like this in my collection when I create one.

```
{
  "articles": [],
  "_id": "5f2dc9780897db6d6dea1f98",
  "name": "New Site",
  "url": "www.newsite.com",
  "__v": 0
}
```

However, when I attempt to create an article, I'm having trouble understanding how to associate that article with a site at the point of its creation, i see this:

```
{
  "source": [],
  "_id": "5f2dca37358c7d74c23105aa",
  "title": "pixel 5 !",
  "author": "Ricky Rojas",
  "comments": 10,
  "__v": 0
}
```

I'm used to using tables for this kind of thing so it's throwing me off a bit - should I be use some kind of foreign key to identify the source id of the article and assigning that? Here is post request located in my /routes/articles.js folder:

```
// @route POST /articles -> adds new instance of an article to the database
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const article = new Article({
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author,
        comments: req.body.comments
        // source: req.body.source,
    })

    try {
        const newArticle = await article.save()
        res.status(201).json(newArticle)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
    }
})
```

Any advice helps here! I think I'm setting up my schema incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to put a relationship in both, just one of them

If you often start queries from articles, put relations only in articles, and vice versa.
and you said the article only has 1 site so you don't need an array sign in the relation. The following is an example of a relationship in the article

```
const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  comments: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  source: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'site' }
})
```

Comment: so @ariffathurrohman, this case, I'd want to refer to the site model in the source key of my ArticleSchema, then remove the articles array in my Site schema?